# What additional functionality is provided by the F-14 nose pitot, absent in early models?

Tags: fighter, feature-identification, pitot-static, sensors, f-14

Early model F-14A had no nose pitot:

[image: F-14s in the 1970s]

[image: F-14s early cruise 1970s]

... but they seem to have quickly acquired them sometime in the late 1970s. The Iranian F-14s have them, and it's quite hard to find a picture of an F-14 without a nose pitot.

This is the nose pitot that appears on the majority of F-14s:

[image: US Navy 020319-N-9849W-013 USS Kitty Hawk]

I believe the nose pitot measures angle of attack, a measurement I would have thought was critical to a big carrier-based aircraft like the F-14 from the outset.

So, why were the nose pitots introduced, and what effect did it have on the nature of piloting an F-14?

Comment: It might help to provide a picture that specifically shows the feature you're asking about, or mark it on the ones above (please also [provide your image sources](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1501/62), by the way). A pitot tube and an [angle of attack vane](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2317/62) are different things, and it isn't clear to me exactly what you're looking at.

Comment: done and done, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The probe on the nose isn't a pitot tube (although it might looks like one).

That's an AoA sensor as explained here: [Home of M.A.T.S. - Sensor Probes](http://www.anft.net/f-14/f14-detail-sensorprobe.htm)

Reported from the link above:

> *Angle-of-Attack Nose Probe: The Angle-of-Attack (AOA) is an essential dimension since it measures the angle between the aircraft's vertical flight direction and the vertical wind direction. A too high AOA means that at a given speed the wings will fail to produce lift which will result in a loss of controllability and stability. This is especially important during the landing phase where the aircraft is fairly slow approaching the carrier and also during air combat maneuvering where a loss of controllability can be deadly. 
>    Each AOA probe measures the pressure at several points and then the AOA is calculated. Usually, several AOA probes are installed to measure a correct AOA.
>    Note that this probe was not installed on very early F-14As*

The [same site](http://www.anft.net/f-14/f14-detail-testequip.htm), on a related page, report what you've alredy found:

> *The first fleet Tomcats were not equipped with any nose probe, but todays F-14s carry a small nose probe to gather air pressure data to calculate the angle-of-attack*

Comment: Thanks - the part I'm struggling to understand is how an aircraft like the F-14 coped without an AoA sensor; or, if it had one (presumably it did), why was there a need for a newer one?

Comment: @PartyArk, if you open the first link, sensors referenced by points 3 and 5 are also AoA sensors, so even early F-14s already had not one but two AoA sensors. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I see that, but I'm still not sure why they felt the need to introduce an extra one?

Comment: @PartyArk: Extra redundancy, perhaps?

Comment: The probes numbered 3 are also labeled "AIC", which is indicated as standing for "Air Inlet Control" and apparently are involved in adjusting the position of air inlet ramps. It's possible data from those probes aren't available to the pilots though I don't really know why that would be done. I don't know what difference there might be between 5 and 1 though.

Comment: Now I am wondering how that probe works. Normally an AoA probe is either a vane—which obviously needs to be on the side—or several pressure sensors around a *curved* wing leading edge. I have trouble understanding on what principle a pointy sensor could measure AoA (as opposed to dynamic pressure, which is then converted to equivalent airspeed).